# SSIS Execute Process starts 64bit Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssis

I have an issue here I can't figure out. I have a powershell script that's using AzureAD module, and it only works in 32bit powershell. However, when I run the script in a Execute Process Task, specifying the 32bit powershell.exe, it's really starts a 64bit powershell (see screenshots).

in option 1, I just copy/paste the entire string in the "executable" line into "windows+r" run window. Then I successfully import AzureAD and you can see it's the 32bit version of powershell.

in option 2, I run the script through SSIS and print out the $PSHome and right there after the script imports AzureAD module and you see the error printed.

What I don't get, is why is SSIS starting a 64bit powershell when I specifically indicate the 32bit exe. Any help appreciated

[image]

Comment: Check the `Run64BitRuntime` option.  In VS in solution explorer, right click the project, properties, under Configuration Properties -> debugging you'll find the option.  Set that to false and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Tim, but I forgot to mention that I already tried that. It didn't help.

Comment: wait... syswow64 is 32 bit library's if you're on a 64 bit machine.   When you run powershell from system32/... that's the 64 bit version, which is what you want.   But since Visual Studio is 32-bit [File System Redirector](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector?redirectedfrom=MSDN) comes into play and is running the 32-bit version from SysWow64 even though you specify system32/....  I bet if you deployed to a server it would work since usually server run-time of packages is 64-bit.   Interesting... Can't think of a work around at the moment...

Comment: try replacing `C:\Windows\System32` with `C:\Windows\Sysnative` in your command.  So it would be  `c:\windows\Sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.  See if that will bypass the file redirector.

Comment: replacing C:\Windows\System with C:\Windows\Sysnative didn't help.
running as is on the PROD system showed the same behaviour.
Actually, just by checking at the start of the script which version of PowerShell is running, it always shows the same when running through Visual Studio and even when giving direct path the the 32 bit version, still the 64 bit was run in all scenarios.

Comment: I think I have to schedule this outside of SSIS, the PS script is producing a CSV that the SSIS picks up and imports into a database. Splitting is not a big deal, just annoying.

Comment: Not sure, I ran a mock test, installed AzureAD and used the Sysnative as my path and did the `import-module AzureAD` and there was no error and it worked. Also, it's 64 bit, AzureAD  only works when ran in the 64-bit version, your error message is telling you at `AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64`.  You could look into just running the powershell directly in a job step and see if that would work for you.

Comment: Running in a job-step worked. I always get the 64bit error when I import, both on my dev machine and the servers. This is frustrating but I don't have time to dig deeper here. Thanks for you input @TimMylott, much appreciated!